# Tensorflow Estimator Graph Size Limitation for large dimensions of input

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I think my entire training data is being stored inside the graph which is hitting the 2gb limit. How can i use feed_dict in estimator API? FYI, I am using the tensorflow estimator API down the line for training my model.

**Input Function:**

```
def input_fn(X_train,epochs,batch_size):
''' input X_train is the scipy sparse matrix of large input dimensions(200000) and number of rows=600000'''

X_train_tf = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((convert_sparse_matrix_to_sparse_tensor(X_train, tf.float32)))
    X_train_tf = X_train_tf.apply(tf.data.experimental.shuffle_and_repeat(shuffle_to_batch*batch_size, epochs))
    X_train_tf = X_train_tf.batch(batch_size).prefetch(2)
    return X_train_tf
```

**Error:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/tmp/apprunner/.working/runtime/app/ae_python_tf.py", line 259, in
>   
>       *AE_Regressor.train(lambda: input_fn(X_train,epochs,batch_size), hooks=[time_hist, logging_hook])*   File
>   "/tmp/apprunner/.working/runtime/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py",
>   line 354, in train
>       loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)   File "/tmp/apprunner/.working/runtime/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py",
>   line 1205, in _train_model
>       return self._train_model_distributed(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)   File
>   "/tmp/apprunner/.working/runtime/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py",
>   line 1352, in _train_model_distributed
>       saving_listeners)   File "/tmp/apprunner/.working/runtime/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py",
>   line 1468, in _train_with_estimator_spec
>       log_step_count_steps=log_step_count_steps) as mon_sess:   File "/tmp/apprunner/.working/runtime/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py",
>   line 504, in MonitoredTrainingSession
>       stop_grace_period_secs=stop_grace_period_secs)   File "/tmp/apprunner/.working/runtime/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py",
>   line 921, in **init**
>       stop_grace_period_secs=stop_grace_period_secs)   File "/tmp/apprunner/.working/runtime/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py",
>   line 631, in **init**
>       h.begin()   File "/tmp/apprunner/.working/runtime/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/basic_session_run_hooks.py",
>   line 543, in begin
>       self._summary_writer = SummaryWriterCache.get(self._checkpoint_dir)   File
>   "/tmp/apprunner/.working/runtime/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/summary/writer/writer_cache.py",
>   line 63, in get
>       logdir, graph=ops.get_default_graph())   File "/tmp/apprunner/.working/runtime/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/summary/writer/writer.py",
>   line 367, in **init**
>       super(FileWriter, self).**init**(event_writer, graph, graph_def)   File
>   "/tmp/apprunner/.working/runtime/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/summary/writer/writer.py",
>   line 83, in **init**
>       self.add_graph(graph=graph, graph_def=graph_def)   File "/tmp/apprunner/.working/runtime/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/summary/writer/writer.py",
>   line 193, in add_graph
>       true_graph_def = graph.as_graph_def(add_shapes=True)   File "/tmp/apprunner/.working/runtime/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py",
>   line 3124, in as_graph_def
>       result, _ = self._as_graph_def(from_version, add_shapes)   File "/tmp/apprunner/.working/runtime/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py",
>   line 3082, in _as_graph_def
>       c_api.TF_GraphToGraphDef(self._c_graph, buf) tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Cannot
>   serialize protocol buffer of type tensorflow.GraphDef as the
>   serialized size (2838040852bytes) would be larger than the limit
>   (2147483647 bytes)

Comment: Can someone please add the tensorflow developers? I dont have credits to add them. I feel this is decent question for large scale tensorflow training.

Answer (score 1):

I'm normally against quoting documentation verbatim, but this is explained word-by-word in the [TF documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets#consuming_numpy_arrays) and I can't find a way to put it better than they already do:

> Note that [using `Dataset.from_tensor_slices()` on `features` and `labels` numpy arrays] will embed the features and labels
>   arrays in your TensorFlow graph as tf.constant() operations. This
>   works well for a small dataset, but wastes memory---because the
>   contents of the array will be copied multiple times---and can run into
>   the 2GB limit for the tf.GraphDef protocol buffer.
>
> As an alternative, you can define the Dataset in terms of
>   tf.placeholder() tensors, and feed the NumPy arrays when you
>   initialize an Iterator over the dataset.

```
# Load the training data into two NumPy arrays, for example using `np.load()`.
with np.load("/var/data/training_data.npy") as data:
  features = data["features"]
  labels = data["labels"]

features_placeholder = tf.placeholder(features.dtype, features.shape)
labels_placeholder = tf.placeholder(labels.dtype, labels.shape)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features_placeholder, labels_placeholder))
# [Other transformations on `dataset`...]
dataset = ...
iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()

sess.run(iterator.initializer, feed_dict={features_placeholder: features,
                                          labels_placeholder: labels})
```

(Code and text both taken from the link above, removed one `assert` in the code that was't relevant to the issue)

---

#### Update

If you're trying to use this with the Estimator API, you're out of luck. From the same linked page, a few sections above the one quoted before:

> Note: Currently, one-shot iterators are the only type that is easily usable with an Estimator.

This, as you noted in the comment, is because the Estimator API hides away the `sess.run()` calls where you need to pass the `feed_dict` for your iterator.

Comment: Thanks GPhilo. I did not mention in my question that i am using tensorflow estimator API down the line. I exactly want to do that but tensorflow estimator API has train function which runs the training and does not take the feed_dict as input. The code sess.run(...) runs inside the train function of estimator. Does any one know how to use feed_dict with tensorflow estimator API?

Comment: That's the kind of info you should add to your question ;) See my update

Comment: They mention "easily usable", I wonder what "easily" means to them. I don't know if there's a way to hack this into working, but my gut feeling is there isn't any at the moment.

Comment: I have tried the one-shot iterators as well but they also store the input when training with estimators API and throw the same error. I hope new tensorflow versions support this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by SessionRunHook if you are using estimator.

Comment: You can add this as a comment. If you want to keep this as an answer, consider adding more details by editing this post.